# How to call SOAP Webservice with security header in blackberry 10 Cascading C /QML?

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am new to BB 10 Cascade.
I need to call SOAP webservice with security header.
How to use qtsoap ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question exactly, how to use QtSOAP with Cascades, or how set a security header on a QtSOAP request?

Comment: My web serivice is autheticated with "wsse:Security" to header.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to add the security header to a QtSOAP request, you can do it this way:
On your `QNetworkRequest`, set the header with `void QNetworkRequest::setRawHeader(const QByteArray& headerName, const QByteArray& headerValue)`, which will give something like this: `request.setRawHeader("wsse:Security", "yourHeaderValue");`

Send your request with `void QtSoapHttpTransport::submitRequest(QNetworkRequest& networkReq, QtSoapMessage& request, const QString& path)`